# I think I need a button to show my own 50 questions per page

Tags: feature-request

I have many questions so having a button to show my own 50  questions per page is very helpful.

I think it is necessary, what do you think?

100 questions per page might not be a big problem for the current situation where many ISP provides fast internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently can't do this on the user page, but it is possible to use the search to only display your questions: use `user:me is:question` as search term. There you can select 50 posts per page.

You can also bookmark this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=is%3aquestion%20user%3ame

Comment: @xport: Note that will not display deleted questions.

Comment: Do we need to request a feature to show the deleted questions? :-)

Comment: @xport: That is status-by-design I think. You can see your own deleted questions on your user page (with all the others).

Answer (score 2):

There's already a button to show 50 questions per page, have a look at the bottom of a browser page:

[image]

Regarding a higher number, that question has been discussed on `meta.stackoverflow.com`:

[Please can we have an extra button (100?) for more questions per page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13122/please-can-we-have-an-extra-button-100-for-more-questions-per-page)

See also:

[Can I get 50 questions on my front page, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/can-i-get-50-questions-on-my-front-page-please)

Jeff recommended in the first of those two topics to use tags for filtering instead of scrolling long lists.

Comment: The button cannot be used for my own questions. :-)

Comment: Well, the first version of the question did not include "my own", meaning your user profile page. At least, that button is shown on the page if you filter by your user name as written by Martin.